# Evaluation inside a Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, evaluation

Let's assume I have a symbolic expression, and inside a `Manipulate` I define the actual values:

```
myf = x + y;
Manipulate[myf, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

doing this I don't obtain the sum of the numbers, so I did

```
Manipulate[Evaluate@myf, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

and is fine, actual numbers are added up. If however I have more expressions:

```
Manipulate[{{Evaluate@myf}, {1 + Evaluate@myf}}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

`Evaluate` does not substitute the `x` and `y` with the actual values.

How can I solve this? More specifically: how to replace symbolic values with actual ones inside a `Manipulate` in the most general case? Hope to have been clear ...

Comment: `myf[x_, y_] := x + y;
Manipulate[myf[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? Your example problem is easily solved by using a function `myf[x_, y_] := x + y`

Comment: I have a pretty complicated Manipulate, with the plot of a symbolic expression function of values set by the manipulate. I knew that the function is the best  option but for some reason I can't manage to define the function (gives me an error), so I was trying with the symbolic expression ...

Comment: Could you present the actual code you are working on? Perhaps this would be a good start to get everyone on board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, to show how to use `Evaluate`, is to apply it to the whole first argument:

```
Manipulate[Evaluate@{{myf}, {1 + myf}}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

With functions like `Manipulate` that hold their arguments, one applies `Evaluate` to the whole argument to override the argument being held.  When it is buried inside another function, even one like `List`, the `Evaluate` has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Best to define a function:

```
myf[x_, y_] := x + y;
Manipulate[myf[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Two different ways of injection:

```
Manipulate[{{#}, {1 + #}}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] & @ myf
```

or

```
With[{myf = myf},
 Manipulate[{{myf}, {1 + myf}}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

Comment: works perfectly fine, thank you, but I accepted the answer from Michael since it came first

Comment: @dario The answer by Michael came last, but I don't mind.